# In Kstreams how to write to kafka in partitioned way based on a particular key in message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

In kstreams High level DSL we have the to method, is there a way if say we want to write the output in partitioned way to kafka, based on a key in the output message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output records are partitioned by the key by default. Additionally, you can provide your own partitioner by this overload of the to() method:

```
void to(StreamPartitioner<? super K,? super V> partitioner,
  String topic)
```

http://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#to(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.StreamPartitioner,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: thanks i will try this, somehow i missed it while searching the api